# How do I debug SQLite source code?

Tags: c, sqlite, makefile

https://github.com/mackyle/sqlite

Above is the source code of SQlite
It use tcl script to concat the whole program into a single file sqlite3.c

What I am currently doing is I use the tcl script provided to split the huge sqlite3.c (see section 2.0 in https://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html#2)
and write a cmake script to allow me to debug it in CLion.

Is there a better/proper way to do it? It would be nice if I could debug in the original file structure .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compile sqlite without the amalgamation into a single `sqlite3.c`. This can be done by passing the `--disable-amalgamation` option to `./configure`:

```
./configure --disable-amalgamation
```